# Get working package data from openProject API using Postman

Tags: postman, openproject

I am trying to get working package data from openProject using api with the help of post man. As per their documentation user name = "apikey" and password  = Token has been set but I am getting this error in the picture.

[image: Click here to see the image]

Answer (score 0):

If you did not deactivate basic auth authentication through the configuration setting `apiv3_enable_basic_auth`, then this setup looks correct and I assume you  are using an invalid API token.

Can you check whether the following command returns a user for you?

**Packaged installation of OpenProject**

```
openproject run bundle exec rails runner "puts User.find_by_api_key('your token').login"
```

**Manual installation of OpenProject**

In your OpenProject installation directory:

```
bundle exec rails runner "puts User.find_by_api_key('your token').login"
```

If this returns your username the token is valid, on error this means your token is invalid.